# Thread.interrupt being called multiple times in Android app, but I only call it once

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This question is really just out of pure curiosity. I have already found a workaround, which I'll explain at the end of the question if anyone is interested.

I have an android app which runs a background thread.  I want to interrupt this thread when a user presses the power key.  In order to achieve this, I have used a BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
public Class MyService extends Service {
  private MyThread myThread;

  //https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/
  private class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      boolean wasScreenOn = true;

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Power key!");
            myThread.interrupt();
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
      }

  }
  private Class MyThread extends Thread {
    private MyObject myObject;
    //various thread functions
    public void run(){
      while(!isInterrupted()){
        //I have code here that waits for the user to let us know to start
        myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.foo();
      }
    }
  }

  public void onCreate(){
    //various setup steps
    myThread = new MyThread();
    myThread.start(); //myThread.run() will get called by this
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, just interrupting the thread isn't enough, because it doesn't poll for interrupt frequently enough:  The thread contains an instance of an object (MyObject), which is running a function (foo), and I can't poll for an interrupt on the thread until foo is done.  To fix this, I implemented a flag within the MyObject class which I can check in foo and break out of the function if necessary (just like how Thread.interrupt works, except MyObject doesn't extend Thread)

```
public class MyObject {
  //other variables
  private boolean isInterrupted;

  public MyObject(){
    //various setup
    isInterrupted = false;
  }
  public boolean foo() {
     while(!isInterrupted){
       //doStuff, return true or false if finished
     }

     return false;

  }
  public void setInterruptFlag(){
    isInterrupted = true;
  }

}
```

With this in place, I override the interrupt method in MyThread:

```
 public void interrupt(){
   Log.d(TAG, "Interrupted!");
   if(myObject != null)
     myObject.setInterruptFlag();
   super.interrupt();
 }
```

This halts the function foo and does more or less what I want.  However, the next time myObject.foo() gets called from myThread.run(), myThread.interrupt() gets called early on and the whole thing halts.  The next run after that is back to normal.

Looking at the log output, I only see the "Power key!" printout when I turn the screen off (as expected).  However, the "Interrupted!" printout occurs 4 or 5 times in quick succession, then again when the user restarts the thread.  The only place I call myThread.interrupt() is directly under the "Power key!" log statement, so I'm confused where the extra calls are coming from.  Does the system automatically call interrupt in some places, and if so, why?

My workaround that I mentioned was to just get rid of the call to myThread.interrupt altogether and instead just expand the scope of myObject so that I can call myObject.setInterruptFlag() directly from the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Not necessarily a solution to your problem, but `isInterrupted` in `MyObject` should probably be declared `volatile`.

Comment: You are 100% right.  I'm actually currently looking into how to use a lock to make isInterrupted behave more nicely, so if you have any suggestions on that I'm open to them.

Comment: My person experience is not to use interrupt. Too many Java classes call interrupt to make it reliable for applications. Use your own interrupt type field. Make it volatile. This way there is never any doubt about who, or why or when. Look at the alternate solutions for using Thread.stop(). Copy that.